# Rails - how to get grouped data from model in array?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, aggregate-functions

I have this structure of data in one of DB table:

```
id | user_id | amount | created_at
 1 |    1    |   3.4  | 2013-09-14 10:10:00 
 2 |    1    |   2.1  | 2013-09-17 10:10:00
 3 |    1    |   7.9  | 2013-09-17 10:10:00
 4 |    1    |   0.2  | 2013-09-16 10:10:00
 5 |    1    |   6.3  | 2013-09-18 10:10:00
 6 |    1    |   11.9 | 2013-09-18 10:10:00
```

The desired output: **[0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0.2, 10, 18.2]** - I would need to get in array summed up the column **amount**  for each day for the respective user for the past 7 days.

So far I am able to get just something like this:

```
Model.where('user_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', current_user.id, week, today).group(:created_at).sum(:amount)
```

which produces data in this format:

```
{2013-09-13 23:00:39 UTC=>5.68, 2013-09-16 23:30:35 UTC=>2.55}
```

Is there any way to get the data in the format I need through just one query?

**EDIT:** Setting up "zero days":

```
  today = Date.today
  week = today - 7
  daily = Model.where('user_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', current_user.id, week, today).group(:created_at).sum(:amount)
  new_value_in_array = false
  unless daily.empty?
    @daily = Array.new
    week.upto(today) do |step|
      daily.each do |d|
        if step.to_s == d[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_s
          @daily << d[1]
          new_value_in_array = true
        end
      end
      if new_value_in_array == false
        @daily <<  0
      end
      new_value_in_array = false          
    end
  end
```

I built this snippet that will check the days within the past week where are no data in database. It's working, but I think it's not very effective, because if I would like to check data for the past month/3 months/6 months, the calculation would take a lot of time.

Any suggestion for more effective solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

```
Model.where('user_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', current_user.id, week, today).group(:created_at).sum(:amount).values
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer `techvineet`, the problem is, that this query generates following output: **[3.4, 0.2, 10, 18.2]** - there are ignored the days when the **sum** operation is zero.

Comment: For the created_at dates which are not there in table, you have to add those date yourself out of query. I don't think you can do it with single query

Answer (score 0):

```
start_date =  Date.today - 7
end_date = Date.today

# get sum for non zero dates
hsh = Model.where('user_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', current_user.id, start_date, end_date).group(:created_at).sum(:amount)
# =>  [3.4, 0.2, 10, 18.2]

#add zero dates to the hsh
start_date.step(end_date,1).map{|d| hsh[d] ||= 0 }
# => [0, 0, 3.4, 0, 0.2, 10, 18.2] 

#dates with zero sum
hsh.select{|k,v| v ==0 }.keys
# => [2013-09-12, 2013-09-13, 2013-09-15]
```